# PHP Download the json file

Tags: php, json, wordpress, file

I have a json data in my wordpress and I want it to be do be download as a file as `.json`.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($wp_options as $key){
    $variable = get_option($key);
    $arr[$key] = $variable;
}
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

I tried `file_put_contents` like

```
$file = 'file.json';
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($arr));
```

but nothing happen.

Any ideas on how this data will can be downloadable as a `.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do next thing:

```
$data = json_encode(['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 1]);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.json');
header('Expires: 0'); //No caching allowed
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
file_put_contents('php://output', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use FILE I/O function. 
try this

```
$fp = fopen('file.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: still no downloadable file prompted. is there anything in the server I must do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the HTTP response headers [Content-Disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) (prompts the user to save the response locally) and [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) (indicates media type) before echoing the JSON data.

```
$data = json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.json');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
```